# Iterating over a data frame while Index is a date

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I wonder if there is away to iterate over a `dataframe` while its index is a date and get the previous indexes without using preset function like `shift()`, `rolling()`, etc ?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
pd.core.common.is_list_like = pd.api.types.is_list_like
from pandas_datareader.data import DataReader 
from datetime import datetime

f = DataReader('F', 'robinhood')
```

**[f.head() outout screenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4fJl.png)**

```
for index, row in f.iterrows():
prev = f.loc[index - someNumber] <----- You cant minus from date
current = f.loc[index]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas has `.iloc` for accessing rows by row number. You can get the current row number using `enumerate`:

```
for e, (index, row) in enumerate(f.iterrows()):
    prev = f.iloc[e - 1]
    current = row
```

**Warning:** During the first iteration (i.e. when `e == 0`), `f.iloc[e - 1]` will get you the last row of of the data frame.

Comment: I get this error Location based index Can only index by location with a [integer, integer slice (START point is INCLUDED, END point is EXCLUDED), listlike of integers, boolean array])

Comment: I had to modify your answer a little bit to suit my situation and now it works, thanks to your guidance